# Joomla upgrade to 3.1.5

Tags: joomla, upgrade

I upgraded joomla from 2.5.14 to 3.1.5 front end is working fine, but the administrator page is not working.

I checked the error log file, it shows, `mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: CacheController::$input in <somepath>/<somefile.php>`
In the line it has, `$this->input->get('view', 'cache');`if I replace the code with `JRequest::getCmd('view', 'cache');` then it is working fine.

so Do i need to find and replace all these lines in Joomla administrator folder?

Please let me know if you have any other smart way to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you upgrade? You can try to disable caching in the config file and purge the cache in the back-end. BTW, there is only one such line (and it is in the CacheController class). It would be interesting to get a trace of that issue, though.

Comment: Yes, I tried by disabling cache and purge the cache. I tried the upgrade from Joomla upgrade menu in component menu.